# I want to ask some grammar from the reading book(six way paragraphs)

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

1. Although he fought the inevitable, in typical fashion, for about a week, he finally die on October 31, 1926.

I don't understand that "he fought the inevitable", as I know "inevitable" is adjective.

2. But the Mount St. Helens cataclysm was only one in a long time of spectacular volcanic eruptions that have occurred over the past hundreds years, **many resulting in** far more damage and loss of life.

I have understood what the sentence means, but I feel that need to add noun between "many" and "resulting".

3. The purpose of the first paragraph is to provide details necessary to understanding the story.

I don't understand "necessary to understanding the story", it should be "necessary to understand the story", shouldn't it?

Thanks for helping .

Comment: would these best be split into 3 separate questions? The first one is about parts of speech, the second about inference and the third about gerunds.

Comment: It's better not to ask several questions in one post. (1) An adjective can be used to mean 'people or things which that adjective describes' (the young, the wounded etc.). Here _inevitable_ means _the unescapable fact that he was going to die_.

Comment: OK @KateBunting  I'm going to separate these questions, thanks .

Comment: @kaipmdh  Thank you for suggestion, I am going to separate these